# Dart generic ... not a subtype of type error

Tags: dart

```
class ActivityItem {}

class Activity<T extends ActivityItem> {
  T item;
  
  Activity(this.item);
}

class Type1ActivityItem extends ActivityItem {
  final String data;
  
  Type1ActivityItem(this.data):super();
}

passType1(Activity<Type1ActivityItem> item) {
  print(item);
}

main() {
  Activity activity = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
  print(passType1(activity as Activity<Type1ActivityItem>)); // ERROR
}
```

In runtime, dart throw

Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'Activity<ActivityItem>': type 'Activity<ActivityItem>' is not a subtype of type 'Activity<Type1ActivityItem>'

Bit confusing to understand when generic type information is getting lost

Scenario 1:

```
  print(Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1')) is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);   // True
```

Dart able to infer the generic type based on constructor parameter

Scenario 2:

```
  Activity activity1 = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
  print(activity1 is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);  // False
```

Looks like at the time of assigning to activity1, generic type information is lost.

Scenario 3:

```
  Activity activity2 = Activity<Type1ActivityItem>(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
  print(activity2 is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);  // True
```

Even after assigning to activity2, generic type still existings ...

Answer (score 1):

> Activity activity = ...

This here is why the error occurs. This gives `activity` the type `Activity<ActivityItem>` which is a distinct type that cannot be downcast to `Activity<Type1ActivityItem>`.

This can be fixed in a couple ways:

1. Specify the generic type in the constructor:

```dart
Activity activity = Activity<Type1ActivityItem>(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
```

2. Specify the generic type in the type declaration:

```dart
Activity<Type1ActivityItem> activity = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
```

3. Use type inference:

```dart
var activity = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
final activity = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
```

### Extended Explanation

```dart
class BaseActivityItem {
  final int base = 1;
}

class SubActivityItem extends BaseActivityItem {
  final int sub = 2;
}

class Activity<T extends BaseActivityItem> {
  T item;

  Activity(this.item);
}

passType1(Activity<SubActivityItem> item) {
  print('passType1 received: $item');
}

main() {
  // The specified variable type will always be the static type of the variable.
  // Here `Activity` is shorthand for `Activity<BaseActivityItem>`.
  // Activity(SubActivityItem()) is a valid value for `Activity<BaseActivityItem>`.
  Activity activity = Activity(SubActivityItem());
  assert(activity is Activity<BaseActivityItem>);

  // `activity.item` runtime type is, as expected, `SubActivityItem`. But, its
  // interface is limited to `BaseActivityItem`.
  assert(activity.item is SubActivityItem);
  print(activity.item.base); // 1

  // The following will not compile because item has type `BaseActivityItem`.
  //print(activit.item.sub);
  // It can be downcast to `SubActivityItem`.
  print((activity.item as SubActivityItem).sub); // 2

  // `activity`'s runtime type is actually
  // Activity<BaseActivityItem> so casting will fail.
  print(activity is Activity<SubActivityItem>); // false

  print('------------------------------------------------');

  // Here we have another activity with the runtime type of
  // Activity<SubActivityItem>. The actual Activity instance
  // is a Activity<SubActivityItem>, but its interface is
  // limited by `Activity` i.e. `Activity<BaseActivityItem>`.
  Activity subRuntimeType = Activity<SubActivityItem>(SubActivityItem());
  assert(subRuntimeType is Activity<BaseActivityItem>);
  assert(subRuntimeType is Activity<SubActivityItem>);
  print(subRuntimeType.item.base); // 1

  // This will fail to compile because item's interface is
  // BaseActivityItem.
  //print(subRuntimeType.item.sub);
  // However it can be downcast:
  print((subRuntimeType.item as SubActivityItem).sub); // 2
  print((subRuntimeType as Activity<SubActivityItem>).item.sub); // 2

  // This can be properly passed to `passType1` because dart knows
  // that `subRuntimeType` is an Activity<SubActivityItem>.
  passType1(subRuntimeType);
  
  print('------------------------------------------------');
  
  // The constructor will return the correct type.
  Activity<SubActivityItem> subType = Activity(SubActivityItem());
  // The following will fail to compile as the constructor return value
  // is not valid for variable type:
  //... subType = Activity(BaseActivityItem());
  //... subType = Activity<BaseActivityItem>(SubActivityItem());
  assert(subType is Activity);
  assert(subType is Activity<SubActivityItem>);
  print(subType.item.base); // 1
  print(subType.item.sub); // 2
  passType1(subType);
  
  print('------------------------------------------------');
  
  // These will infer the type from rhs:
  var inferVarType = Activity(SubActivityItem());
  final inferFinalType = Activity(SubActivityItem());
  print(inferVarType.item.sub); // 2
  print(inferFinalType.item.sub); // 2
  passType1(inferVarType);
  passType1(inferFinalType);
}
```

Comment: Bit confusing to understand when generic type information is getting lost

Scenario 1:
`  
  print(Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1')) is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);   // True
`
Dart able to infer the generic type based on constructor parameter

Comment: Scenario 2:
`
  Activity activity1 = Activity(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
  print(activity1 is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);  // False
`
Looks like at the time of assigning to activity1, generic type information is lost.

Comment: Scenario 3:
```
  Activity activity2 = Activity<Type1ActivityItem>(Type1ActivityItem('data1'));
  print(activity2 is Activity<Type1ActivityItem>);  // True
```
Even after assigning to activity2, generic type still existings ...

Comment: It appears that when specific generic type information is not given, it uses the widest type available within its constraints. For example, the widest type for Activity's `T` is `ActivityItem`. If you were to remove the `ActivityItem` constraint from T the widest type would be `dynamic`.

Comment: It does seem weird since using `var` will infer the specific type.

Comment: Thxs for ur reply. This doesn't explain why in scenario 3, generic type information is not lost but in scenario 2 it is. My guess is ... in scenario 1, dart uses constructor parameter type to infer generic type.  In scenario 2, it uses variable type(Activity) to infer type.  In scenario 3, since type is provided explicitly when creating the instance, dart uses it.  In scenario 2, i would expect dart to chose specific type(using constructor parameter type) instead of variable type.  But don't know why dart uses variable type instead in scenario 2.

Comment: I'm sorry about the late reply. I've been thinking about this and I think we've been overthinking. It turns out it's just polymorphism and specifying types. Scenario 2 doesn't lose type information; it's a valid value for `Activity<ActivityItem>`. Scenario 3 instance is of type `Activity<Type1ActivityItem>` with the `Activity<ActivityItem>` interface. See my answer for an extended explanation.